# verticalNormalizedPosition not precise or wrong calculation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scroll

i want the user to be able to navigate through options in a scrollview while the middle option keeps centered. ever when i return the verticalnormalizedposition it updates, but it's not precise enough... what i mean is, as i go down in options, the "centered" position is going lower and lower and eventually ends up being outside the scrollview...
the maximum allowed options in the scrollview is 5. so i start updating the scrollview when it's going below option 2. and try to keep it centered...
option's height is 30,
scrollview's height is 150,
resultParent's height is (25 options * 30) 750. Hope anyone can help me solve this...

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            GameObject currentSelected = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
            int i = OptionObjects.IndexOf(currentSelected);
            if (i > 1 && i < OptionObjects.Count - 2)
            {
                StartCoroutine(CalculateScrollPos(i));
            }
            else if (i < 3)
            {
                Mask.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition = 1f;
            }
            else if (i > OptionObjects.Count - 3)
            {
                Mask.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition = 0f;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            GameObject currentSelected = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;
            int i = OptionObjects.IndexOf(currentSelected);
            if (i > 1 && i < OptionObjects.Count - 2)
            {
                StartCoroutine(CalculateScrollPos(i));
            }
            else if (i < 3)
            {
                Mask.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition = 1f;
            }
            else if (i > OptionObjects.Count - 3)
            {
                Mask.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition = 0f;
            }
        }
```

and for the calculation:

```
IEnumerator CalculateScrollPos(int value)
{
    float r = ((resultParent.sizeDelta.y - 30f) - ((value-2) * (resultParent.sizeDelta.y / resultParent.childCount))) / (resultParent.sizeDelta.y - 30f);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    Mask.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalScrollbar.value = r;
}
```

Comment: [SOLVED] so i had to subtract the scrollview's height from the resultparent height when calculating the new verticalnormalizedposition. code looks like: `IEnumerator CalculateScrollPos(int value)
    {
        float r = ((resultParent.sizeDelta.y - Mask.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y) - ((value-2) * (resultParent.sizeDelta.y / resultParent.childCount))) / (resultParent.sizeDelta.y - Mask.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta.y);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        Mask.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalScrollbar.value = r;
        yield break;
    }`

Comment: Comments aren't meant for answers. You can submit an answer below. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information!